# Layout issue on Android with FrameLayout and ScrollView

Tags: android, layout, scrollview, android-framelayout

I'm trying to split the screen in 2 areas, to the left an `ImageView` and to the right a `ScrolView`. I'm adding the `ImageView` and the content of the ScrollView programatically, so the xml file of the layout looks like this:

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    >
    <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/scene_view"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="left"
            >
    </FrameLayout>
    <ScrollView
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_width="@dimen/scrollmenu_width"
            android:layout_gravity="right"
            >
        <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/scrollmenu"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                >
        </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>
</FrameLayout>
```

What am I doing wrong? because I'm getting the `ScrollView` to the right, but the `ImageView` centered (relative to the screen) placed on the left of the screen. The resolution of the image exceeds the screen's resolution so I get black sp

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you should make use of the `LinearLayout` and the `weight` parameter to solve this problem.

I have edited your snippet to give you an idea of how you should use it.

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:orientation="horizontal">

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/scene_view"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="left"
        android:layout_weight=1>
    </FrameLayout>
    <ScrollView
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_weight=1
        android:layout_gravity="right">
        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/scrollmenu"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent">
        </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>
</FrameLayout>
```

I hope it helps..

Comment: ahhh, I knew that was possible, just that I'm new to Android and it didn't cross my mind in this situation. Thanks, the solution worked, although that's not how you write the weight parameter on `LinearLayout`

Comment: Sorry for the mistake, I am glad I was able to help.