# ScrollView rolling behind a framelayout

Tags: android, android-layout

I am having some battles with a scrollview and a framelayout. Despite trying numerous things no matter what I do the scrollview seems to fill the parent and stick some of my content behind the framelayout.
What I want is the framelayout across the bottom and the scrollview to fill the top section. Can anyone point out the silly mistake I am making here?
I tried what was suggested here [Layout issue on Android with FrameLayout and ScrollView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8693648/layout-issue-on-android-with-framelayout-and-scrollview) but that didn't do it.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/quizresultlayout"
style="@style/Activity"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<ScrollView
    android:id="@+id/resultscroll"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_above="@+id/frameLayout1"
    android:fillViewport="true" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/sublayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tvResultMsg"
            style="tvtemplatemedium"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:tag="@string/quizresults_CongratsMsg"
            android:text="@string/quizresults_CongratsMsg" />

        <TableLayout
            android:id="@+id/resultable"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" >
        </TableLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>

<FrameLayout
    style="@style/bottomframe"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true" >

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="92dp" >

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/btnstartquiz"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:src="@drawable/play" />

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/btnRptCard"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:src="@drawable/chart" />

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/btnTrunk"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:src="@drawable/play" />
    </RelativeLayout>
</FrameLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do this:

change the root RelativeLayout to LinearLayout.

set the ScrollView android:layout_height="0dp"

add to ScrollView android:layout_weight="1"  <-- this will make your scrollview fill the remaining space and will push the framelayout at the bottom.

Comment: Worked like a charm! I tried the linearlayout before but I guess I didn't have the weight set. Figured it was something stupid like that. Thanks very much for the help!